# unconstrained type parameter in rust

Tags: generics, rust, types, substrate

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```rust
pub struct DataProvider;

impl<T: Config> DataProvider {
    fn details() -> T::AccountId {
        Author::<T>::get().map(|a| a.into())
    }
}
```

But getting this error:

```
impl<T: Config> DataProvider {
     ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

I have tried several things but didn't solved.

Comment: The issue is because `DataProvider` doesn't use the type parameter `T`. You can move the type parameter to the `details` function itself to solve this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `Config` trait for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).